# Elasticsearch 5.0.0. cluster node not joining

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, cluster-computing

Ok this shouldn't be this hard, I'm trying to run 2 nodes in an elasticsearch cluster and getting an exception when trying to start node-1(node-2 which is master is already started). Using elasticsearch v 5.0.0 for both instances

**Exception:** failed to send join request to master, reason RemoteTransportException can't add node found existing node with the same id but is a different node instance]

**Node-1 config:**

node.name: SANNNNN-1

network.host: 10.3.185.250

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.3.185.251:9300"]

**Node-2 config:**

node.name: SAN-2

network.host: 10.3.185.251

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.3.185.251:9300"]

**Full Exception on node 2:**

[INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [SANNNNN-1] failed to send join request to master [{SAN-2}{DxExoYHHTu2-rFvuvQSuEg}{OfYBe97HQCmcha63CFiYlQ}{10.3.185.251}{10.3.185.251:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[SAN-2][10.3.185.251:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[can't add node {SANNNNN-1}{DxExoYHHTu2-rFvuvQSuEg}{hP4gLRugRgWzSuNnEhGHSw}{10.3.185.250}{10.3.185.250:9300}, found existing node {SAN-2}{DxExoYHHTu2-rFvuvQSuEg}{OfYBe97HQCmcha63CFiYlQ}{10.3.185.251}{10.3.185.251:9300} with the same id but is a different node instance]; ]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok so the issue was copying the elasticsearch folder from one node to another over scp. Elasticsearch saves the node id in elasticsearch/data/ folder. Deleted the data folder on one node and restarted it. The cluster is up and running. Hope this saves someone the hassle.

Comment: Why did you select your own 'late' answer while the other 'previous' answer pointed out the same solution...?

Comment: See the year as well.

Comment: Saved a good amount of time for debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the directory `<Elastic search home>/data` and restart the ES node,  this issue is due to elastic search storing id in this directory, and this is a common mistake when copying one working elastic search directory from one node to another.

after fixing the issue, check the cluster status like this:

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health"`

works fine with `elastic search 6`  as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after cloning a Data Node in Azure. I ended up finding the Data file by starting in the root folder:

/datadisks/disk1/elasticsearch/data

I kept reading that others found the folder elsewhere and wanted to share here.