# ElasticSearch VM clone - master_not_found_exception, found existing node with the same id but is a different node instance

Tags: elasticsearch, virtualbox

Here is my setup:

Two instances of Ubuntu 16.04. Second one is clone made from the first one. ElasticSearch is installed only on Guest (Ubuntu) OSes. Configuration has been adjusted after cloning the VM.

I am running with bridged network in VirtualBox - each instance got its IP from the router. Windows (host) firewall is configured appropriately. All machines can ping each other. Ping, Netstat and nmap testing shows that ports 9200 and 9300 are OPEN (tested "remote" hosts also).

ElasticSearch service is running appropriately. I can "curl -XGET" both locally and remotely and get the correct results.

The problem is that the ES from the second machine is not joining the cluster.

Here are the configuration files:

First one:

```
cluster.name: p4g4n_cluster
node.name: master
node.master: true
network.host: 192.168.0.12
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.0.12", "192.168.0.17"]
```

Second one:

```
cluster.name: p4g4n_cluster
node.name: node1
node.master: false
network.host: 192.168.0.17
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.0.12", "192.168.0.17"]
```

if I try `curl -XGET 192.168.0.17:9200/_cluster/health` I will get `master_not_discovered_exception`. And if I try basic GET request, I will see that the `node1` has *_na_* for the `cluster_uuid" property, while on first machine - *master*`cluster_uuid` is present.

Version of ElasticSearch running is: 5.4.0 and
Version of Lucene is: 6.5.0

Can anyone help me with what needs to happen in order for `node1` to see and join the cluster?

Comment: Try changing `network.host: 0.0.0.0` in both servers.

Comment: It's not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue.

Digging through the logs showed that this was not a network configuration issue.

Since I first configured the entire ELK stack on one machine and then cloned it, the ES and logstash were already running and pumping syslog logs into the elastic.

Because of this, the cloned machine had the same data folder as the existing one. As it turned out, the node UUID is embedded in the data folder and the solution was to delete the data folder on the cloned VM.

The error that I found in logs was: **found existing node {xxx} with the same id but is a different node instance** ... So there was an obvious conflict.

I found this [github ES issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21405) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486411/elasticsearch-5-0-0-cluster-node-not-joining) that dealt with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0 in both servers